# Why does Typescript assume every branch in this switch statement to be "never"?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to access the properties of an object via bracket notation. For this I created a `const enum` which represents a subset of the keys of said object.
Now, depending on what key is used, I want to perform an operation or just return the correct value.
However, for every branch in the switch statement (even the `default` branch!!), Typescript shows me this (of course for numbers it's `number` and for undefined in the default case it's `undefined`):

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UserInput[T]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

Here's the code:

```
const enum UserInputInfo {
    Name = 'name',
    StartTime = 'start',
    ValidUntil = 'validUntil',
    Target = 'target',
    Url = 'url',
    Title = 'title'
}
interface UserInput {
    start: number;
    target: string;
    title: string;
    validUntil: number;
    url: string;
    name: string;
    getName: () => string;
    some: boolean;
    other: string;
    props: number;
}
// errors happen in each return line
function getUserInputInfo<T extends UserInputInfo>(infoType: T): UserInput[T] {
    const userInput: UserInput = null as any as UserInput; // this is just to simplify the code snippet
    switch (infoType) {
        case UserInputInfo.Name:
            return (userInput ? userInput.getName() : '');
        case UserInputInfo.ValidUntil:
            return (userInput ? userInput.validUntil : 0);
        case UserInputInfo.StartTime:
            return (userInput ? userInput.start : 0);
        case UserInputInfo.Target:
            return (userInput && userInput.target);
        case UserInputInfo.Url:
            return (userInput ? userInput.url : '');
        case UserInputInfo.Title:
            return (userInput ? userInput.title : '');
        default :
            return void 0;
    }
}
```

What is Typescript trying to tell me? How can I fix this issue? It seems the only workaround is to assert each return value to `as UserInput[T]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is because of a change introduced in TypeScript 3.5 to [improve the soundness of writing to an indexed access type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).  In TypeScript 3.4 and below, your code would not have produced an error (well, except for returning `undefined` at the end, which the compiler doesn't consider unreachable).  In no version of TypeScript (to date, up to TS3.8) is the compiler actually able to verify that your code is safe; it's just that in older versions the compiler would silently fail to catch actual errors (e.g.,  `case UserInputInfo.Name: return 1`) whereas in newer versions the compiler loudly fails to validate safe code like you've got.

The underlying problem is: you've got a generic value `T extends UserInputInfo` which is a union of (essentially) string literals, and you're using control flow (via `switch`/`case`) to try to figure out which `T` you've got and act accordingly. But the compiler does not use control flow analysis to narrow a generic type parameter `T` from `UserInputInfo` to, say, `UserInputInfo.Name`.  There's a longstanding open GitHub issue about this, [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085).  Not sure if there will ever be much traction there but you might want to go and give it a  if you want to slightly increase the chance that it will be addressed.

---

Until then, we have workarounds.  By far the easiest one is to use an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) so that the implementation of your function is intentionally more loosely typed.  This is sort of like reverting to the pre-TS3.5 behavior for unions:

```
function getUserInputInfo<T extends UserInputInfo>(infoType: T): UserInput[T];
function getUserInputInfo(infoType: UserInputInfo): UserInput[UserInputInfo] {
    const userInput: UserInput = null as any as UserInput;
    switch (infoType) {
        case UserInputInfo.Name:
            return (userInput ? userInput.getName() : '');
        case UserInputInfo.ValidUntil:
            return (userInput ? userInput.validUntil : 0);
        case UserInputInfo.StartTime:
            return (userInput ? userInput.start : 0);
        case UserInputInfo.Target:
            return (userInput && userInput.target);
        case UserInputInfo.Url:
            return (userInput ? userInput.url : '');
        case UserInputInfo.Title:
            return (userInput ? userInput.title : '');            
    }
}
```

That suppresses compiler warnings, and isn't *completely* unsafe, since you can't return something nutty like `{a: 1}` when the compiler expects `string | number`.  But if you return a `number` where there should be a `string`, or vice versa (e.g., `case UserInputInfo.Name: return 1`), it will happily compile (as in TS3.4-) and you'll get runtime errors (e.g., `getUserInputInfo(UserInputInfo.Name).toUpperCase()`).

---

Another workaround ([mentioned in a comment by person who implemented the soundness change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559)) is to take advantage of the fact that if you have a value `t` of type `T`, and a key `k` of type `K extends keyof T`, then the type of `t[k]` will be seen by the compiler as `T[K]`.  So if we can make a valid `UserInput`, we can just index into it with `infoType`.  Maybe like this:

```
function getUserInputInfo2<T extends UserInputInfo>(infoType: T): UserInput[T] {
    const userInput = null as UserInput | null;
    const validUserInput: UserInput = {
        get [UserInputInfo.Name]() { return userInput ? userInput.getName() : '' },
        get [UserInputInfo.ValidUntil]() { return userInput ? userInput.validUntil : 0 },
        get [UserInputInfo.StartTime]() { return userInput ? userInput.start : 0 },
        get [UserInputInfo.Target]() { 
          return (userInput && userInput.target) || '' }, // not sure
        get [UserInputInfo.Url]() { return userInput ? userInput.url : '' },
        get [UserInputInfo.Title]() { return userInput ? userInput.title : '' },
        some: false,
        other: "",
        props: 1,
        getName: () => ""
    }
    return validUserInput[infoType];
}
```

That's more or less a translation of your `switch`/`case` version into an object indexing operation (except that `target` might be `false` in your version, which is not a `string`).  In actual code I'd expect that there'd be less of a mismatch between `UserInput` and `UserInputInfo`, or you could use `Pick` like this:

```
function getUserInputInfo3<T extends UserInputInfo>(
  infoType: T
): Pick<UserInput, UserInputInfo>[T] {
    const userInput = null as UserInput | null;
    const validUserInput: Pick<UserInput, UserInputInfo> = {
        get [UserInputInfo.Name]() { return userInput ? userInput.getName() : '' },
        get [UserInputInfo.ValidUntil]() { return userInput ? userInput.validUntil : 0 },
        get [UserInputInfo.StartTime]() { return userInput ? userInput.start : 0 },
        get [UserInputInfo.Target]() { 
          return (userInput && userInput.target) || '' }, // not sure
        get [UserInputInfo.Url]() { return userInput ? userInput.url : '' },
        get [UserInputInfo.Title]() { return userInput ? userInput.title : '' },
    }
    return validUserInput[infoType];
}
```

---

Okay, hope one of those helps you; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-UsQ2MxQADEP57RRwXGxKQMXREoZItTzmlyv61vYK21zziwVYEeTwuYHPcceUnBxPBcQpHzsZ8sDrT9dQAMgQzdL2LOoXH-BcgPlWFBWLPxpigqsa1g1c3w3eDtymPsuEHYdc3zYCi2vMIOiI2gYLg8iPzfNDEwiGiB0w2gEgSKhWVBaRwUhN84QAJkRFE0TADEmNwsh8TTYVyXsKUcKgBklWzM9wGgFCOz1RADTNTF9JgAAfEorM0O5VTM3c9DfbULI4Yycy8GA5VkvCy0ZXsKEXEiOUo99zPFLsXDLXt+04GA4h8BcAqCy9J2nPdrDCrNIuXUiYoo3iPNnA8YEPNKMsrLL9MnW8JHvOBCsoYqVzKnjUJ-GjavSx9GuCkswK8DqIs4sjLxgJC4q-dCoF2ezHIHOrbXtMAHkOII4GGlxAqavCCMmrrSu4hacmLaiUrqg7YGyjtQP49rwvO6LLpiviYkE1KhoA04NlSTRMHqnMHmeLBigAIhh8G7A+L4fhgABGBG6G7DZezYA44ZqBJoKimBKrfOktIzZl4ioGhxOBSTpK5UaQAAZkUuBUXRWzmc0wVtIpKUAAVpGAABreF9P4NSrz2QzlRHUz1XIjh9UNbnZsc1XXMVkmLE8y9imFsWJbfKXjo0+Q-LsEacpC3gzumnqru3LG4GS2j7oAm3nrwvLBgK97Ha+iq9aqgbPcyw6nonPCWqkWQ3qKoPZt6jtvw8X8aojhqo-NlinBcB3idfWb5u+paVrW-6pbtEodogPaHqO5n8P8IuSs+lPnc7W6PYByPHrz4tWMTzrk4s1P4vaVg7v7kSamm0nL3JvnKYBIA)

Comment: funny, i already added a comment to that github issue, so in the end it seems to be the same problem i already had before, just a bit of a different scenario. thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is telling you that you're extending an enum, which can be any string.

So `UserInput[anythingOtherThanDefinedEnumKeys]` is `never`, because UserInput doesn't have all the keys.

You can just do:

```
function getUserInputInfo(infoType: UserInputInfo): UserInput[UserInputInfo] {}
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem. using `UserInputInfo` doesn't give typescript enough information to infer the correct return type (in this case it's just `string | number`, while it can be exact provided the correct property key). in your case, `anythingOtherThanDefinedEnumKeys` is simply not possible, because `T extends UserInputInfo`. `UserInputInfo` is a subset of `keyof UserInput`, thus it can never be something else. the enum is never extended. or do i misunderstand and typescript tries to infer the type from the return type instead of the function argument?